# NSURLSessionDataTask don't work in child thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

As title
`NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];` Now I want to use `NSURLSessionDataTask` to replace it.But I have a problem, that is, NSURLSessionDataTask did not return the data successfully
I tried to break the breakpoint and found it running in the main thread, but it doesn't run.

[image]

[image]

```
//1 on main thread
NSURLSessionDataTask *loadDataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:URL completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    // don't work
    dataU = data;

    TFHpple *hpple = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:dataU];initWithHTMLData:dataU];

    NSString *pathQueryString = @"//div[@class='newslist l']/ul/li/a"; //
    NSArray *Nodes = [hpple searchWithXPathQuery:pathQueryString];

    for (TFHppleElement *element in Nodes) {

        MKNewsItem *newsItem = [[MKNewsItem alloc] init];

        // 6
        newsItem.title = [element text];
        newsItem.time = [[element firstChildWithTagName:@"span"] content];
        NSMutableString *tempTime = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", newsItem.time];
        [tempTime replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@""];
        [tempTime replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(10, 1) withString:@""];
        newsItem.time = tempTime;

        newsItem.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[element objectForKey:@"href"]];

        NSMutableString *tempUrl = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ayit.edu.cn%@",newsItem.url.absoluteString];
        [tempUrl deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(22, 2)];  //删除那两个..
        newsItem.url = [NSURL URLWithString:tempUrl];
        [newsGroup addObject:newsItem];
    }
    _news = nil;
    _news = newsGroup;

}];

//2  
[loadDataTask resume];
```

The main line to the implementation of the `NSURLSessionDataTask`

Comment: Put the breakpoint on the `dataU = data;` line instead of the `dataTaskWithURL` line. Is the new breakpoint reached?

Comment: New breakpoints can be reached, The main line to the implementation of the first DataTask ,then to implement the main thread`NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];`  And then go back to the implementation of sub threads `NSURLSessionDataTask *loadDataTask`

Comment: Sorry but your issue isn't clear. What problem are you actually having?

Comment: I want to return data from `NSURLSessionDataTask` and process it, but it don't do it.Now I added the original statement `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];` in the back, to be able to perform, but obviously this is not consistent with my view

Comment: You are not providing any useful information for anyone to help. You have posted a lot of code inside your completion handler. What exactly isn't working inside that code block?

Comment: sorry, I want to say `NSURLSessionDataTask` is not carried out in a child thread, and is not executed.

Comment: It is executed. Otherwise the new breakpoint wouldn't be hit. You cannot return data from the task. It is asynchronous.

Comment: So what you're saying, if I'm understanding correctly, is that a synchronous load with `dataWithContentsOfURL:` from a background thread works, but that an asynchronous load with `NSURLSession` is not running the completion block.  Is the main thread blocked by any chance?  `NSURLSession`, unless you configure the session with a different delegate queue, calls its callbacks on the main thread (or maybe the thread where the session is created—I forget which).  If that thread is blocked, it won't get as far as running the completion block.